# Can't change my MYSQL privileges for granting a remote access to user

Tags: mysql, sqoop

I am trying to connect to a MySQL server using sqoop but I am getting connetction errors. I searched a bit and got to know that I need to give remote access privileges to the user for which I am running:

```
GRANT all privileges on *.* TO 'ujjwal'@'1.2.3.4' identified by 'pass!word' with GRANT OPTION;
```

But I am getting a syntax error-

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'identified by pass!word' with GRANT OPTION' at line 1
```

Could you please let me know what mistake I am doing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you can use `IDENTIFIED BY` on a `GRANT` command?

Comment: No I am not, what do you suggest using instead?

Comment: Where have you read that you can use `IDENTIFIED BY` on a `GRANT` command?

Comment: I found it here- https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#id1773570